# How to design to save a field of a aggregate root in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I learned DDD recently, we used to encapsulate the creation, update, deletion in to the repository to persist the changes to the DB.

With ORM tools, we can ignore the detail of the persistence, usually the argument of the repository is an aggregate root object, and the ORM execute the conversion of the persistence(for example, it will update one field if there just one change).

But if without ORM, there is just a field of the aggregate root object changed and save it to DB, how to design this for repository? support a method to save this field? There is a method called update to save all properties, but with it, it will cause performance issue.

Answer (score 4):

To persist changes only you need to know what changed, obviously. There are two common ways to achieve this:

1. **Track changes as they occur**. This strategy is easier to implement when the entity explicitely participates to the change tracking mecanism. For instance, with [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) the Aggregate Root would [record uncommitted change event(s)](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/Domain.cs#L63) in a collection for all commands it processed.
2. **Dirty checking: compare the new state to the old state**. Note that the old state may be cached for performance optimizations.

Comment: @RonSmith Did you forget your question?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need another Repository. How it is implemented is up to you. 
You can write the code so it is able to save/update just single fields when they change.

If you want to update single fields as they change one way to do this is to use an Observer to "observe mutations" in your objects. This approach can have two "operation modes"

- Ad-hoc: When a field gets updated persist just this field's value right away.
- Aggregate update: Gather the information of all updated fields (just the fact that they were updated not the data). Then update them all at once when the time comes

This approach can have other performance implications in a large system. You have to see if it suits you or not.

Another option would be to have your ORM recognize the changed fields at the time of the update via a comparison. This again has its own performance implications since you will have to fetch the DB object (aggregate) once more and compare it against the runtime changes.

How you actually implement any of these heavily depends on the language you're using and its utilities. Performance issues also heavily depend on the language/runtime platform/3rd party software and lots of other things.